# Hyperlink font in Excel always changes to the default font face/size

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2003

For cells containing hyperlinks the font changes automatically into the default one (even though I have selected all cells and applied a different font).

How can you configure Excel to use the same font face/size as you selected for the entire sheet (or group of cells) and not the default font set in Excel (in Excel 2007 the font can be set in Excel Options | Popular tab | When creating new workbooks section).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a new default template that will load at startup. They didn't make it easy to do in Office 2007! But here's how:

1. Open a new blank worksheet.
2. Insert > Hyperlink > Paste in any link
3. Home > Styles > Right click on the 'Hyperlink style' > Modify > Set your font options
4. You probably will want to do the same for the 'Followed Hyperlink' style
5. Delete the hyperlink.
6. File > Save As > Other formats
7. Browse to "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART" (Copy/Paste that into the File name field and press Enter to get there easily)
8. Save as type: Excel Template (.xltx)
9. File name: Book.xltx

Now whenever you start Excel or create a new workbook, the hyperlink font should be the one you choose.

This Microsoft support article helped me: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822107 look here for where to save templates for Office 2003, or to see other ways of loading your template.

Comment: Thank you subman! Maybe if I tried harder I could've found the answer myself - pretty intuitive the Style section though... Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the default Hyperlink within the Styles list. Right click on the *Hyperlink* style and select *modify*. Select *format* and set your font, color, size, underline, border, etc..

Comment: I wonder what the compatibility is for this answer.  It's 100x simpler than the accepted answer.