# How to change default font size in Microsoft Excel for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, fonts, microsoft-excel-2011, 4k-resolution

I'm using Microsoft Excel for Mac 2011 and by default, a new spreadsheet has a font size of 12 for cells. On a 4k screen resolution, font size 12 is a bit small, so I have selected the whole spreadsheet and updated every cell to now be font 16, however, whenever I paste a hyperlink, the font size on the cell becomes 12. Similarly, whenever I apply the preset format from the ribbon for Green background "Good" it also becomes font size 12.

How can I change the default font size for this spreadsheet to be 16? Similarly, is there a way to change the default for all new spreadsheets to be 12?

Comment: I think [changing your default zoom](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/is-it-possible-to-change-the-startup-zoom/ac8106fd-b2af-4f3a-8e37-8692f48d4ad9) would be a better idea than changing font sizes - this way, people you send your Excel docs to who _don't_ have 4K monitors will still be able to read them.

Comment: To change all new spreadsheets to 12, go to Excel > Preferences > General > Standard Font > '12'. To change the hyperlink pasting font, follow this [articles](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/mac-excel-help/customize-how-excel-opens-workbooks-and-sheets-HA102927598.aspx) instructions, the template being an excel document with your desired customisations. Use the first 4 instructions on [this](http://superuser.com/questions/30814/hyperlink-font-in-excel-always-changes-to-the-default-font-face-size?rq=1) link - it tells you how to make the template customisations. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Did my suggestion eventually work?

Comment: @shub Thus far I've only tried the change for all new spreadsheets which works even for setting hyperlinks for new spreadsheets, but I'm not sure how to apply that to existing ones.

Comment: Ah... OK, I also do not know how to apply them to existing ones. Sorry